# Суть платформонезависимости Java

Tags: java, jvm

Обычно, когда новичкам рассказывают про преимущества Java, упоминают платформонезависимость. Я правильно понял, что разработав Java-приложение, мы можем его собрать в несколько установочных файлов под каждую ОС, и теперь оно будет работать на каждой из этих ОС?

Comment: Собирать под каждую ОС можно на любом языке программирования, это тут ни при чём. Суть джавы в том, что собрать можно *один* раз например в jar-файл, и этот единственный jar-файл будет работать *везде*, где есть java (jvm)

Comment: А вот уже сама Java для каждой ОС своя.

Comment: Ну примерно как на С/С++. Если есть компилятор под вашу архитектуру, какой-бы странной она ни была, то можно собрать ваше приложение под эту архитектуру. В случае Java головную боль по сборке берут на себя создатели JVM и этим экономят  вам время и нервы. Само приложение остается как есть, его собирать каждый раз не надо. Косяки JVM, GC и прочие в комплекте )

Comment: @andreymal если только нативные библиотеки не используются.

Comment: @Suvitruf ну нативные библиотеки это уже и не совсем java :)

Comment: @andreymal почему же. Java приложения часто используют нативные уже готовые библиотеки. Как правило, это всякие sdk и т.п. Хорошо, если там есть .so'шки под различные архитектуры, но не всегда всё так радужно...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Платформонезависимость Java опирается на существование виртуальной машины Java (JVM) на каждой поддерживаемой платформе.

На разных платформах JVM разные. Но программы на Java могут запуститься на любой из них (если не учитывать различные версии Java), поскольку собираются **не в родной формат платформы**, а в промежуточный код JVM, обычно называемый **байткодом**.

Можно считать, что Java и её платформа это два разных языка. Для первого компиляторы есть у разработчиков приложений, а для второго компиляторы есть и у пользователей. И с языком платформы мало кто работает напрямую, даже среди разработчиков (если только с какими-нибудь экзотическими целями вроде глубокого профилирования или разработки под JVM нового языка — коих, кстати, полно).

---

Ещё один нюанс: **нативные (родные для платформы) расширения**, которые расширяют возможности Java да пределы стандартных библиотек, **платформозависимы**. То есть, чтобы сохранить платформонезависимость Java в необходимой мере, нужно используемые расширения подготовить для *каждой* нужной платформы отдельно.

---

Что касается версий Java, о чём я упомянул выше — платформа развивается и обрастает новыми возможностями. Поэтому версия Java, которой программа была собрана, должна поддерживаться теми версиями JVM, в которые вы целитесь.

Разработчики JVM очень уважают обратную совместимость, и в большинстве случаев собранную на **старой версии Java** программу *получится* запустить **на новой JVM**. Но поскольку поддержка старых версий без существенного сдерживания новых довольно сложна, не стоит рассчитывать, что все старые версии языка будут поддерживаться вечно.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подробный комментарий!